# Unable to navigate through bottom tabs in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

App.js

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Tabs.js

```
const Tabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='Team' screenOptions={{tabBarShowLabel: false, headerShown: false}} >
            <Tab.Screen 
            name="Home" component={Main} 
            options={{
            tabBarButton: props => (<TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Main')} />),
            // tabBarIcon
            }} 
            />
            <Tab.Screen 
            name="Team" component={Team} 
            options={{
            tabBarButton: props => (<TouchableOpacity {...props} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Team')} />),
            }} 
            />
          </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
const Home = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
            
              <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Schedule">
                  <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} 
                    options={{
                      title: 'Main',
                      headerShown: false
                    }}
                  />
                  
                  <Stack.Screen name="Team" component={Team} 
                    options={{
                      title: 'Team',
                      headerShown: false
                    }}
                  />
              </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  };
```

This is what I did. The screens with Main and Team.
I'm unable to navigate through these screens.
What is the issue with this implementation? And please help me to navigate through screens.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `tabBarButton` tries to navigate to `Main` but the name you're using for the tab route is `Home`.

I'm assuming you intended to use the `Home` component in the first tab instead of the `Main` component.

I tried to create this snack with a working example: https://snack.expo.dev/9a0DOgzoB

`Please do not use the same route name for multiple routes. You're using Team multiple times.`

Comment: Thank you so much, I just needed to add useNavigation(). Thanks again!